# Regex in Python for all nums and hyphen any where in the text

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I need regex to match the below:

```
1. 34224-2343
2. 32423434242-23234
3. 1-324235
```

The hyphen can be anywhere in the string and the string will have all nums.

I have the below but it is not working:

```
text = "43-2765936"

if text.replace("-","") and all(char.isdigit() for char in text):
    print ('yes')
```

Comment: `if all(char.isdigit() for char in text.replace("-",""))`

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your code to:

```
text = "43-2765936"

if all(char.isdigit() for char in text.replace("-", "")):
    print ('yes')
```

Strings in `Python` are immutable and `text.replace("-", "")` does not change the original `text` variable.

---

To ensure that there's only one `-` in your string use some logic:

```
text = "43-2765936"
cleaned = text.replace("-", "", 1)

if "-" in text and cleaned.isnumeric():
    print("yes")
```

Or a regular expression altogether:

```
^(?=[^-]*-[^-]*$)[-\d]+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/VzI1Fx/1/).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could shorten it using [isnumeric()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) on the result of first replacing `-` with an empty string.

```
text = "43-2765936"

if text.replace("-", "").isnumeric():
    print ('yes')
```

Output

```
yes
```

---

If there has to be a digit present and as most a single `-`, you can also use a pattern and assert for a digit to be present:

```
 ^(?=-*\d)\d*(?:-\d*)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=-*\d)` Assert at least a single digit
- `\d*` Match optional digits
- `(?:-\d*)?` Optionally match `-` and optional digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Lay2U/1)